# Editing color of textures

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, color

I have these two textures and I want to change the white or grayish parts in the images to glowing red or normal red can anybody tell me how to change the color of textures.

[image]

And

[image]

The color I want is like this

[image]

Comment: More flexible would be to use the textures as a mask in your shader tree... probably as a `Fac` in a _Mix RGB_ node

Answer (score 1):

try to copy these nodes and change the colours and values where you need to.
[image]

[image]

In your case the secondary colour you want is red so change the 'colour 1' in the multiply node from plain white to red.

remember color ramp node is optional

HOPE THIS HELPED!!

Comment: Super thanks to you

Comment: @Avinas Your welcome!! happy it worked

Answer (score 1):

- Plug Image node directly into *Emission Strenght* of Principled BSDF
- Change Emission color to Red

Comment: Huh... why didn't i think of this :D